# How to style elements if first-child hasClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 `.school`, several `.class-room` and there are some `.my-child` inside.

If `.my-child` is located in the first `.class-room` of a school, I want to style that school with yellow background.  But it doesn't show as expected.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjsv47Lw/8/)

```js
$('.school').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.my-child').each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).addClass('child' + (i + 1));
  });
  if ($('.school .class-room:first-child').children().hasClass('.my-child')) {
    $('.school').css('background', 'yellow');
  }
})
```

```css
.my-child.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.my-child.child2 {
  background: green;
}

.my-child.child3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `.school > .class-room:first-child > .my-child {` suffice?

Comment: @j08691 Because they want to style the `.school`, not the `.my-child`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey hmmm, could be. Unclear.

Comment: [.firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest moving the code for selecting the school outside of your `each` loop. Then, use the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to find the school.

```js
$('.school:has(.class-room:first-child>.my-child)').addClass('has-my-child');
```

```css
.my-child.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.my-child.child2 {
  background: green;
}

.my-child.child3 {
  background: blue;
}

.has-my-child { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this might be slower than using plain old JavaScript:

```js
const school = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.school')).filter(school => school.querySelectorAll('.class-room:first-child > .my-child').length === 1)[0];
if (school) {
  school.classList.add('has-my-child');
}
```

```css
.my-child.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.my-child.child2 {
  background: green;
}

.my-child.child3 {
  background: blue;
}

.has-my-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the dot in hasClass:

change:

```
.hasClass('.my-child')
```

to:

```
.hasClass('my-child')
```

I would also use $(this) in your conditional to only select the correct school to change the background color of:

```
if ( $(this).children('.class-room:first-child').children().hasClass('my-child') )
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5wxaoj1m/

Edit: Updated to address concerns from comments and I added a jsfiddle link.

Comment: If you make that change to the OP's code it colors both schools as yellow and it appears as if that should only happen if my-child is in the first class-room of a school

Comment: Also, "don't need" could perhaps be better worded as "cannot use". With the dot at the beginning it's looking for class=".my-child".

Comment: Good catch @j08691, added new/appropriate conditional syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using index with eq and is(':first-child')

```
$(this).children('.class-room').eq(0).children('.my-child').is(':first-child')
```

1. First .class-room with eq(0)
2. Check my-child is first or not using children('.my-child').is(':first-child')

```js
$('.school').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.my-child').each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).addClass('child' + (i + 1));
  });
  
  if($(this).children('.class-room').eq(0).children('.my-child').is(':first-child')){
    $(this).css('background', 'yellow')
  }
  
})
```

```css
.my-child.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.my-child.child2 {
  background: green;
}

.my-child.child3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="school">
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="my-child">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-room">
    <div class="other">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mYbBEj

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could get away with getting rid of the JavaScript and doing it all on CSS.

Add this to your CSS:

```css
.class-room:first-of-type > .my-child { background: yellow; }
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: As noted in the comments, I believe the OP wants the element with class "school" to have the background-color change, not the one with "my-child".